# how to transform Map<String,String> to List<String> using google collections

Tags: java, guava

I have a map with strings, I want to transform it to a list of strings with " " as a key value separator. Is it possible using google collections?

Code example that I want to do using google collections:

```
public static List<String> addLstOfSetEnvVariables(Map<String, String> env)
{
    ArrayList<String> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : env.entrySet())
    {
        result.add(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go:

```
private static final Joiner JOINER = Joiner.on(' ');
public List<String> mapToList(final Map<String, String> input){
    return Lists.newArrayList(
        Iterables.transform(
            input.entrySet(), new Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>(){
                @Override
                public String apply(final Map.Entry<String, String> input){
                    return JOINER.join(input.getKey(), input.getValue());
                }
            }));
}
```

Update: optimized code. Using a Joiner constant should be much faster than String.concat()

---

These days, I would of course do this with Java 8 streams. No external lib needed.

```
public List<String> mapToList(final Map<String, String> input) {
    return input.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new StringBuilder(
                             e.getKey().length()
                                     + e.getValue().length()
                                     + 1
                     ).append(e.getKey())
                      .append(' ')
                      .append(e.getValue())
                      .toString()
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Functional programming is cool, but in Java often adds complexity you really shouldn't be adding (as Java doesn't support it very well) I would suggest you use a simple loop which is much shorter, more efficient and eaiser to maintain and doesn't require an additional library to learn.

```
public static List<String> mapToList(Map<String, String> env) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : env.entrySet())
        result.add(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    return result;
}
```

A simple test of code complexity it to count the number of symbols used. i.e. < ( , { = : . + @
Not counting close brackets.

```
plain loop 22 symbols.
functional approach 30 symbols.
```

Comment: given this problem where a List is required, I agree. If the return type was iterable, however, Guava's `Iterables.transform()` would be favorable, because it is only a transformed view of the original collection (i.e. the values would only have to be iterated once, in the client code)

Comment: @Sean, again, this is cool, but what is the advantage of doing this?

Comment: if the collection is large enough, it will make a noticeable difference in Performance and Memory usage, I guess. But to me the main advantage is that I can get different views of a collection without actually copying or changing it.

Comment: Not to mention, the reason why Google uses Iterables so much is because one of the core ideas about Iterables: You don't exactly know if everything you're iterating over is in main memory. An Iterable could be streaming data in it's underlying implementation, which might not fit in main memory. By wrapping an Iterable in a transforming function and transform as you read, you no longer need to depend on a bad assumption about Iterables (Which only just happens to be true 98% of the time).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a functional approach using Java 8 streams:

```
List<String> kv = map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()) //or String.format if you prefer
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you're not wedded to the functional style, here's a more concise variant of the obvious for loop:

```
List<String> kv = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> kv.add(k + " " + v));
```

Answer (score 2):

### More Current solution

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final Map<String, String> m = ImmutableMap.of("k1", "v1", "k2", "v2", "k3", "v3");
    final Collection<String> c = Maps.transformEntries(m, new Maps.EntryTransformer<String, String, String>()
    {
        @Override public String transformEntry(@Nullable final String key, @Nullable final String value)
        {
            return Joiner.on(' ').join(key, value);
        }
    }).values();
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

#### Outputs

```
[k1 v1, k2 v2, k3 v3]
```