# Java Map<String, String> to List<String> using Guava

Tags: java, list, dictionary, guava

I have a

```
java.util.Map<String, String>
```

and is there anyway in guava to convert that to a

```
List<String>
```

with only the values from the map?

Comment: You don't need Guava for this.

Answer (score 16):

Why not just do

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write:

```
List<String> list = ImmutableList.copyOf(map.values());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());
```

**EDIT**

If you really need to use guava try it as [follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895376/how-to-transfom-mapstring-string-to-liststring-using-google-collections)

```
public List<String> mapToList(final Map<String, String> input){
    return Lists.newArrayList(
        Iterables.transform(
            input.entrySet(), new Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>(){
                @Override
                public String apply(final Map.Entry<String, String> input){
                    return input.getValue();
                }
            }));
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't use Guava

Comment: Your edit doesn't make a list of values, it makes of list of space-separated entries.

Comment: Great answer after EDIT, because I needed to transform the value in the process. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate yourselfe through the map and add each value to the list.
Where is the problem?